# Powerpoint - Text Changed Using VBA Reverts During Transition

Tags: vba, ms-office, powerpoint

I have some VBA in a Powerpoint presentation. It changes the text of a slide after the slide has transitioned.

The presentation is on a loop.

The problem I have is that *after* the change, during the transition effect on subsequent loops the text momentarily reverts back to its value *before* it was changed, only to flick back again after the transition.

```
Dim bChanged As Boolean
Public Sub OnSlideShowPageChange(ByVal Wn As SlideShowWindow)
    If Wn.View.CurrentShowPosition = 2 Then
        If bChanged = False Then
            ActivePresentation.Slides(2).Shapes("Header").TextFrame.TextRange.Text = "Changed"
            bChanged = True
        End If
   End If
End Sub
```

Comment: In some versions of PPT, folks have found that moving the shape completely off the slide then back onto it gives PPT the whack in the head it needs to make it realize that something's changed and the (probably cached bitmap of the slide) needs updating.

Comment: Thank you, @SteveRindsberg. I am using 2010. I tried that, as well as removing and adding the transition but no luck, I'm afraid.

Comment: Not sure what else might be causing the problem, then, I'm afraid